# Finding the Intersection of Arrays

Tags: java, optimization, array

I would like any advice on how to improve this code. To clarify what this code considers an intersection to be, the intersection of [3,3,4,6,7] and [3,3,3,6,7] is [3,6,7]. I would appreciate any improvements to make the code more readable or perform faster.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> findIt (int[] a, int[] b){
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < a.length && j < b.length){
        if(a[i]<b[j])
            ++i;
        else if (a[i] > b[j])
            ++j;
        else{
            if (!result.contains(a[i]))
                result.add(a[i]);
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Examples of given arrays are already sorted. Are all given arrays sorted? If result ArrayList can not contain duplicate elements, maybe Set would be better?

Comment: Since the answers are using `List`s instead of arrays as input, I'll ask directly: Any special reason you are using arrays? It's very unusual to use arrays in Java, because `List`s are much more flexible. Generally, unless you need to optimize extremely for speed, you should reconsider using arrays at all.

Comment: You mean "intersection".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Algorithm

You're using a O(n log(n)) algorithm here, which could be O(n²) for difficult cases since `contains()` is O(n) and is called in a loop. Instead, use the property of `HashSet`: access is O(1), which means you can achieve this in O(n) time. My algorithm below simply keeps track of what it can add to the result. I can add everything that exists in the first list, but I should not add an item I already added.

See my tested code for my implementation:

```
public static List<Integer> intersection(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){
    Set<Integer> canAdd = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int n: b) {
        if(first.contains(n)) {
            result.add(n);
            // we wish to add only one n
            canAdd.remove(n);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Comments on your code

1. You should return a `List`, not an `ArrayList` since it's an implementation detail. Using an `ArrayList` is OK here since adding at the end of it has O(1) amortized complexity. Otherwise, lists should be `LinkedList` (when adding to the beginning, not to the end, as @Landei points out).
2. Be careful about the names you choose. `findIt` doesn't seem to be appropriate, but `removeDuplicates` or `intersection` describes what the code does.

Comment: I agree with everything except with the `LinkedList` comment. Benchmarks show that `ArrayList` is almost always preferable. See e.g. http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue111.html

Comment: You use a reference `first`, but it isn't defined (your code won't compile).  If it's `a` or `b`, you have a nasty side-effect.

Comment: @Landei Oops, I meant to use addFirst. Since it's not always available in the `List` interface, I'll switch back to ArrayList. @X-Zero Opps, that's `canAdd`, I forgot to change that one.

Comment: @seand Haha, so this is why I couldn't understand what an "interception" was.

Answer (score 3):

What about ? It's clean.

```
public static List<Integer> intersection(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int v : a) {
        if(b.contains(v) && !result.contains(v)) {
            result.add(v);
        }
    }

    // sort if you need
    Collections.sort(result); 

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's simply a performance issue: `List.contains` takes a lot of time compared to `HashSet.contains()`: O(1) vs O(n). Otherwise, it's nice and easy to read, here's an upvote. :)

Comment: Side note: you should use `for (Integer` instead of `for (int` because you're unnecessarily boxing and unboxing as a result.

Answer (score 3):

@Cygal : Assuming that HashSet.contains() is really faster than the List one, this could be the ultimate code :-)

```
public static List<Integer> intersection(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
    Set<Integer> bSet = new HashSet<Integer>(b);

    for(Iterator<Integer> it = aSet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if(!bSet.contains(it.next())) it.remove();
    }

    return new ArrayList<Integer>(aSet);
}
```

Comment: The `new HashSet` trick is nice, but [The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling `remove()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()). Bien tenté!

Comment: 'aSet' is a local variable so it cannot be modified from anywhere else. It should be good :-) Merci !

Comment: I don't know if this is about concurrent accesss or "removing while doing a for loop". Maybe this works and is specified, but I would not do this in production code unless I was sure. (That's forbidden in C++, by the way.)

Comment: In Java, the only way to remove an Object from a collection is to use an Iterator. This note is applicable only if there is a concurrent access. Trust me, it works well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CollectionUtils` utility in [Apache Commons Collection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). There is `intersection` method in this class. I will write my utility for your case in following:

```
public <T> Collection<T> intersection(T[] one, T[] two)
{
    List<T> list_one = Arrays.asList(one);
    List<T> list_two = Arrays.asList(two);

    List<T> intersection = (List<T>) org.apache.commons.collections
                                                       .CollectionUtils.intersection(list_one, list_two);

    return intersection;
}
```

I hope my answer will useful for you.